# How to add HTML5 attribute "autocomplete" to form fields?

Tags: 8, forms, webforms

According to an accessibility test, I have to add the HTML5 attribute "autocomplete" an the proper tags to all form fields on my website where the user fills in his/ her personal data.

E.g. "Your E-Mail" > `autocomplete="email"`, "Your Family Name" > `autocomplete="family-name"`, etc. (The proper tags are listet in the WHATWG HTML standard https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofill)

Some of the fields are in Drupal core (like the user registration form), others are webforms (like an event registration).

What is the best way to achieve this in Drupal 8?

Comment: I think there is no general way to do it for all fields, you will have to do it with custom code for example with  `hook_form_alter` something like `$form['your_field']['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'your_autocomplete_value';`

Comment: This post has some good info for webforms that might be helpful:  http://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/drupal/drupal-8-webform-alter-change-fields-labels-hiding-fields-custom-validate-and-submit

Comment: Just wanted to note that Webform module now has support for adding autocomplete tags per HTML 5.2 spec: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3113160#comment-13464333

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to add this attribute to all input fields using a bit of JS, something like this should work:

```
(function($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.autocompleteFieldBehavior = {
    attach: function (context) {
      $(context).find('input').each(function () {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        if ($(this).attr('autocomplete').length === 0) {
          if (name) {
            $(this).attr('autocomplete', name);
          }
          else {
            $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'Default autocomplete value.');
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

The other solution would be alter all forms using `hook_form_alter`, see @berramou's comment.